# How to break a for loop and convert integers?

Tags: c++, for-loop

My program needs to calculates the cost for customers
to replace their carpet at $5 per yard for installation, various padding options, 
carpet cost and total all rounded up to the nearest yard.
Padding is cost is based on:

1. Good - $3 per yard  - 1-3year warranty
2. Better - $4 per yard 3-5 year warranty
3. Best- $5 per yard -  5-10 year warranty
4. Excellent - $7 per yard 10-20 year warranty

Operation:

1. Prompt User for number of rooms For each room:
2. Prompt length than width for each number of room
3. Calculate square feet  a. convert square feet to square yards and round up  b. square yards = yards required for room  c. Calculate installation cost by square yard *$5
4. Prompt user to choose padding.   a. Multiply padding cost by square yard of room
5. Prompt user for carpeting cost per sq yard of room:  a. Calculate cost by multiplying input by squareyards required
6. Output total yards required
7. Output Installation cost
8. Output padding cost
9. Output carpet cost
10. Output total cost = + Installation + PAdding + Carpet
11. Grand total = cost of each room

****************************/

I have 5 problems so far:

1. How to convert the integer padding choice to the cost of the quality
2. The floor loop will not break between rooms
3. When it displays the room number it starts at 0
4. How do I get the dollars to display to 2 decimal places?
5. How will I get the total of each rooms to store as doubles to get the grand total?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <string>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   const float INSTALL_COST = 5;
   const float GOOD_PAD = 3;
   const float BETR_PAD = 4;
   const float BEST_PAD = 5;
   const float EXC_PAD = 7;
   const double SQU_FT_YD = 9;

   int main () 

   {

   int padding, rooms, numreq, squareYards;
   double length, width, squareFeet,priceSquareYard;
   double paddingCost, installFee, totalCost, carpetCost;

   //step 1:

   cout << "Enter number of rooms: ";
   cin >> numreq;
   cout << endl;

   //Step 2
   cout << "Enter length of room: ";
   cin >> length;
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Enter width of room: ";
   cin >> width; 
   cout << endl; 

   //step 3

   cout << "Select quality of padding:<1-4> ";
   cout << "\n1. Good - $3 per yard  - 1-3 year warranty \n2. Better - $4 per yard 3-5 year warranty \n3. Best- $5 per yard -  5-10 year warranty \n4. Excellent - $7 per yard 10-20 year warranty: ";
   cin >> padding;
   cout << "Enter price of carpeting per square yard of room: ";
   cin >> priceSquareYard;
   //step3

   for(int x = 0; x < numreq; x++)
   {   
   squareFeet = length * width; 
       squareYards = ((squareFeet / SQU_FT_YD) + 0.5);
       if (squareYards > 0)
           squareYards++;
       installFee = squareYards * INSTALL_COST;
       carpetCost = priceSquareYard * squareYards;
       paddingCost = squareYards * padding;
       totalCost = carpetCost + installFee + paddingCost;
       cout << "\n Room " << x << " Yards Required = " << squareYards;
       cout << "\n Room " << x << " Installation = $"  <<installFee;
       cout << "\n Room " << x << " Padding Cost = $" << paddingCost;
       cout << "\n Room " << x << " Carpet Cost = $" << carpetCost;
       cout << "\n Room " << x << " Total Cost = $" << totalCost; 
   }


   _getch();
   return 0;
   ```

   }

Comment: It would seem that step 2 & 3 should also be inside the for loop.  If you grouped all the data for each room in a class or struct and added them to a vector it would be much easier to calculate and display the data later.

Answer (score 0):

To get totals within loops, simply store a variable outside of the loop, start it at 0, and increment it within the loop whenever necessary.

And you can use `break;` to break out of the loop completely. Also, if you need this, `continue;` will let you stop the current iteration and jump straight to the next iteration of your for-loop.

And for number 4, check this out:
[NumberFormat/DecimalFormat treats certain floating-point values as longs instead of doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938834/numberformat-decimalformat-treats-certain-floating-point-values-as-longs-instead)